# Mediacapture.Dispose() method not found

Tags: c#

I am trying to use media capture class to recording a video from webcam. I am able to record video successfully.However when I try to use _mediacapture.Dispose to free the unmanaged resources. But VS pops up with an error dispose method not found.

Where and how can I find the `dispose` method? In case if I need to implement dispose method, how do I go about it?

Please note that I am implementing Desktop Apps.

Comment: please provide a link to the documentation of the Mediacapure class.

Comment: Could you show us your code?